# How many neurons should be in the last layer of the neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I use the following code to classify movie reviews into three classes (negative as -1, neutral as 0, and 1 as positive). But is it true that there is only one output neuron in the last layer for the three-class classification problem?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy as K

csvfilename_train = 'train(cleaned).csv'
csvfilename_test = 'test(cleaned).csv'

# Read .csv files as pandas dataframes
df_train = pd.read_csv(csvfilename_train)
df_test = pd.read_csv(csvfilename_test)

train_sentences  = df_train['Comment'].values
test_sentences  = df_test['Comment'].values

# Extract labels from dataframes
train_labels = df_train['Sentiment'].values
test_labels = df_test['Sentiment'].values

vocab_size = 10000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 30
trunc_type = 'post'
oov_tok = '<OOV>'

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token = oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_sentences)
padded = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen = max_length, truncating = trunc_type)

test_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_sentences)
test_padded = pad_sequences(test_sequences, maxlen = max_length)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length = max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

num_epochs = 10
model.fit(padded, train_labels, epochs = num_epochs, validation_data = (test_padded, test_labels))
```

When I changes `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')` to `tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')` it gives me the following **error**:

```
---> 10 model.fit(padded, train_labels, epochs = num_epochs, validation_data = (test_padded,test_labels))
     ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

Comment: you need to have as many outputs as you have distinct classes (i.e.  3). the error you ar e getting is saying your labels do not match up with your outputs. so first encode your labels accordingly (that is each class should have a distinct label)

Comment: Thanks! @Rika. Do you mean that I must change labels to something like [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have 3 neurons if you are classifying between 3 categories.

Also, you should use the `'softmax'` activation for your final layer, assuming that all observations are in one class only.

Next, you should use `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` since your input is not one-hot encoded. Targets like `[0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]` are optional, you can also have `[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0]`.

Finally, your targets should be `[0, 1, 2]` and not `[-1, 0, 1]` so I suggest you add 1 to your labels.

```
test_labels = df_test['Sentiment'].values + 1
```

This is what happens if labels are `[-1, 0, 1]` instead of `[0, 1, 2]`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sparse_entropy = tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

a = tf.convert_to_tensor([[-1., 0., 1.]]) #+ 1
b = tf.convert_to_tensor([[.4, .2, .4], [.1, .7, .2], [.8, .1, .1]])

sparse_entropy(a, b)
```

```
nan
```

If you uncomment the `+1`, which transforms the labels into `[0, 1, 2]`, it works:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.1918503>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

One hot encode your train labels and use categorical crossentropy as loss function.

**Cause:**

1. Your logits have shape (n,2) but labels have (n,1).
2. Your logits and labels should be of shape (n,3) if youre using crossentropy(unless it is sparse).

**Solution:**

1. One hot encode the train labels and you'll get train labels shape (n,3)
2. Use categorical crossentropy with final dense neuron having 3 outputs, then you'll get logits shape(n,3)

Your model will start learning after this.

Comment: That's not always `True`. Their labels are not one-hot encoded but they can still use crossentropy loss. Also there will be another problem, see the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I assumed sparse_categorical_entropy is not commonly used hence I ignored it. Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

You got 3 classes -> num_classes=3
Your last layer should look like this:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation = 'sigmoid'),
```

You will receive a np.array with 3 probabilities as output. Moreover, you should change your class to categorical_crossentropy because you are not solving a binary problem.

Comment: Thanks! @MareSeestern. But as I said, when I change num_classes to more than one, it gives an error.

Comment: Yes, which error throws it? Did you change your loss function?